# Lua: First Call to Function OR VM Launch/Startup Check

Tags: function, logging, lua, call, init

I want to know if there is a way to check if a function has been called at least once before or if there this is the first call to the function (through any methods) OR If there is a way to check if the Lua VM or application just launched/started up...the former being preferred. Then to check if the application/Lua VM is closing and do a quick final call.

Here's my function

```
function __Error(error)
    local error_log = io.open("Logs/Error.log", "a+")
    local log_time_date = os.date("Error Log: %A, %B %d %Y %I" .. ":" .. "%M" .. ":" .. "%S %p")
    local errors = "-----\n" .. log_time_date .. "\n\n" .. error .. "\n"
    error_log:write(errors)
    error_log:close()
end
__Error("This is an error")
```

It's an error logging function that will be used in multiple scripts, functions, classes, etc that will log all errors to a single file. The thing I want to do is make the time_data only appear on the first call of this function as it's not needed after that and looks bad. So is there a way to do this with this function? I prefer not changing the arguments sent to it and the date_time variable  if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a closure:

```
do
    local first = true -- __Error can access/modify this, and it will persist across calls
    local error_log -- Same here

    function __Error(error)
        if first then
            -- Repeatedly opening/closing the log file is bad for performance, just open it once and keep it open.
            -- Also, don't need + in the file mode if you're not reading.
            error_log = io.open("Logs/Error.log", "a")
            local log_time_date = os.date("Error Log: %A, %B %d %Y %I" .. ":" .. "%M" .. ":" .. "%S %p")
            local header = "-----\n" .. log_time_date .. "\n"
            error_log:write(header)
            first = false
        end

        error_log:write(error, "\n")
    end

    function __Close_error_log()
        if error_log then error_log.close() end
    end
end

__Error("This is an error")

-- at end of program
__Close_error_log()
```

Comment: Looks solid, I will test it. If I want previous logs to be preserved don't I need the +?

Comment: I tested it and it still came up with the time date on the second call. Does it work for you?

Comment: Make sure you're not creating the function multiple times. Also yea you don't need `+` to keep the contents if you're `a`ppending.

Comment: The function is only created once from what I can see. While the closure allow for the function to be called in external scripts as long as it's in the global table?

Comment: Here's the output I get on your script...`-----
Error Log: Sunday, November 09 2014 07:37:37 PM
This is an error
-----
Error Log: Sunday, November 09 2014 07:38:10 PM
This is an error
Hi

Hi` I called the function twice with Hi\n, but any other time I call the function, the time prints.

Comment: It works fine for me. Again, be sure you're not running the code multiple times, as it will create a new closure each time it runs.

Comment: Yeah, just saw that myself...it does run multiple times and that's partially the problem. This script will be in another script which acts as a control script that executes various other scripts. This is a global function I wanted to use. Is there any way to get around that?

Comment: @B1313: Change the `do` to `if not __Error then`. You can also automate calling `__Close_error_log` by making it the `__gc` method of an upvalue for `__Error`.

Comment: Wouldn't this be valid solution as well? (READ my answer [coding messed up in comments]) Or is there some reason it's a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
logged_time_date = logged_time_date

function __Error(error)
    local error_log = io.open("Logs/Error.log", "a+") -- a+ is needed in case the file gets deleted
    if logged_time_date == nil then
        local log_time_date = os.date("Error Log: %A, %B %d %Y %I" .. ":" .. "%M" .. ":" .. "%S %p")
        local time_stamp = "----\n" .. log_time_date .. "\n----\n"
        error_log:write(time_stamp)
        logged_time_date = true
    end
    error_log:write(error, "\n")
end
```

This was the answer me and my friend came up with. Would this be valid?